# Android service and thread id

Tags: android

So, I have two standalone Android projects.

One is an app and the other is a service. The service is configured to run on it's own process.  When I run them and print the thread details I get name = `main` and id = `1`.

My initial belief was that both the service and app would run on different processes and therefore different threads.

It looks like they are running on the same thread. Perhaps the answer is that there is a thread named `main` for each process, plausible and that the thread ids are all per process, meaning two processes could have threads with the same id.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread ID you are observing is not Native thread ID, it is an ID of given Thread instance.
Of course native threads would have unique IDs but you are not getting their IDs.
Now considering the above statement, different processes can have Thread instances with equal IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each process has its own main thread

Answer (score 0):

You have right. Each process has own main thread.